# Haskell and Emacs

Tags: haskell, emacs, haskell-mode

I'm trying to learn Haskell. I have configured Emacs for Haskell development, I followed this blog post:

http://tim.dysinger.net/posts/2014-02-18-haskell-with-emacs.html

The system works but I always get this error:

> Error (el-get): while initializing haskell-mode: Symbol's value as variable is void: haskell-mode-map

I looked up the files and the variable is defined, I do not know why this is happening.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add

```
(require 'haskell-mode-autoloads)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error when trying to run

```
(define-key haskell-mode-map [f8] 'haskell-navigate-imports)
```

in .emacs

But using eval-after-load fixed it. I couldn't get the require to work. YMMV

```
(eval-after-load 'haskell-mode
      '(define-key haskell-mode-map [f8] 'haskell-navigate-imports))
```